# Using CrudRepository to retrieve a DiscriminatorColumn in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am currently working on a project using Spring Boot.

One of the tables I'm working with is using a DiscriminatorColumn, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "document_summary", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"document_name", "document_type"}))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "document_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class DocumentSummary {
     ...
     //no document type field
     ...
}
```

As you can see, even though a column on the table is called "document_type", it is not explicitly created as an individual field.

Normally, I would just create a repository like this to retrieve the Document Summary from the databse:

```
public interface DocumentSummaryRepository extends CrudRepository<DocumentSummary, Long> {
    DocumentSummary findByDocumentType(String documentType);
}
```

In this case, is there a way to retrieve Document Summary data based on the column document_type?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the way to do this.

Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-two-crud/

Going through the two ways, you can see how and what column to call in this scenario.

Also, in the section concerning wrong way of doing it, you will also see that:

1. Create a base interface that extends the Repository interface and
   add the common methods to that interface.
2. Create the actual repository interface that extends our base interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `findBy` method in your repository interface:

```
public interface DocumentSummaryRepository extends CrudRepository<DocumentSummary, Long> {
    DocumentSummary findByDocument__type(String documentType);
}
```

Use double underscore here because Spring treats it as a reserved character: [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)